# Template error when refining a lambda expression for use in MVC InputFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, linq-expressions

In my application I have several (>10) places where I have a model like this:

```
public interface IOptionList
{
    string Name;
    bool Checked;
}

public class Option : IOptionList { }

public class MyModel
{
    public Option[] Options = 
    {
        new Option { Name = "Option 1", Checked = false }
    };

    // etc... for many more implementations of IOptionList
}
```

These are used to generate CheckboxLists in views like so:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Length; i++)
{
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Options[i].Checked)
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Options[i].Checked, Model.Options[i].Name)
    </div>
}
```

Because this is used so many times I'd like to simplify my models by writing an `HtmlHelper` extension to generate the lists like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFormGroupFor(x => x.Options, Model.Options)
```

and my current attempt looks like this:

```
public static CheckBoxFormGroupFor<TModel, TItem>(this HtmlHelper<TModel>html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TItem[]>> expression, TItem[] values)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        var indexExpression = Expression.ArrayIndex(expression.Body, Expression.Constant(i));
        var checkedAccessExpression = Expression.Property(indexExpression, typeof(ICheckboxList), "Checked");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(checkedAccessExpression, Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel)));
        var cbx = html.CheckBoxFor(x => lambda.Compile()(x));
        var lbl = html.LabelFor(x => lambda.Compile()(x), values[i].Name);

        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.InnerHtml = $"{cbx}{lbl}";
        sb.Append(div);
    }
    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

which as I understand extends the initial lambda expression `x => x.Options` to access the correct property of the object at the correct array index, however this gives me a template error with the message

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

As far as I can see I'm only doing a single-D array index followed by property access so I'm not sure why I'm seeing this. I'd previously tried `var cbx = html.CheckBoxFor(lambda);` but this doesn't work as the parameter `x` is only defined in the scope of the view.

Assuming what I want is even possible can anyone help with how to achieve it? I'm new to manipulating `Expressions` in this way.

Comment: Not clear what your wanting to pass to the method - your currently passing the same model in both parameters. I any case, why not use an `EditorTempate` for and simply `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Options)` (and the error is because of `x => lambda.Compile()(x)` which makes no sense but again, not sure what your trying to achieve with that

Comment: You can do all this in half the code, and the signature should be just `public static CheckBoxFormGroupFor<TModel,>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<IOptionList>>> expression)` if your always passing an array of `IOptionList`

Comment: Yes I considered using `IEnumerable<IOptionList>` but in order to index the list I would need to call `ToArray` on it (`Expression.ArrayIndex` *only* works on arrays) and templates for MVC's *For methods can't contain method calls - it would break the model binding.

Comment: You can make it work fine (the same way the inbuilt HtmlHelper methods work which use ModelMetadata). But its still not clear why you do not just create an `EditorTemplate` for type of `Option` (containing just `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Checked)`and `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Checked, Model.Name)`) and just use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Options)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. Using directly the `lambda` variable

```
var cbx = html.CheckBoxFor(lambda);
var lbl = html.LabelFor(lambda, values[i].Name);
```

is indeed the right way. Just make sure the lambda expression your are composing uses the same parameter as the `expression` argument (since it's bound to the body used in the new expression), i.e. here

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(
    checkedAccessExpression,
    Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel)));
```

replace `Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel)` with `expression.Parameters[0]`:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, bool>>(
    checkedAccessExpression,
    expression.Parameters[0]));
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I wasn't aware `expression.Paramaters` existed, that makes a lot of sense now.